# ¿Como copiar contenido de una lista enlazada en un archivo de texto en C?

Tags: c, lista

me gustaría saber como podría copiar el contenido de una lista enlazada en un archivo de texto creado en tiempo de ejecución.

Tengo esta parte de código pero no funciona:

```
printf("Nombre de fichero destino: ");
scanf("%s", copia);
if ((fp = fopen (copia, "w")) == NULL ){ 

    printf("ERROR. NO se puede crear el fichero destino %s\n", copia);
    printf("\n\n");
    system("pause");
    return 1; /* Salimos de la funcion main. Terminamos el programa */
}

while(aux!=NULL){

    fputc(aux, copia);

    aux = aux->sig;
}
```

aclaro que aux es un puntero que apunta al primer elemento de la lista para poder recorrerla elemento a elemento.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Tu pregunta está incompleta: No has puesto el tipo de `aux` y conocemos su estructura. No queda claro qué se debe guardar en el fichero. No has indicado por qué no te funciona el código (que no te funciona es obvio pero... ¿cómo debería funcionar? y decir _bien_ no vale en este contexto).

Comment: El segundo parámetro de `fputc` espera un archivo (`fp`), no un nombre de archivo (`copia`), y el primer parámetro espera un `int` (un caracter) no un puntero a una lista, si quieres guardar una cadena debes utilizar `fputs(aux->mi_cadena, fp);`

Comment: Tampoco estas cerrando el archivo